# Where to write custom code (CRUD) in WordPress

Tags: mvc

I am new to WordPress development and I am wondering what is correct/standard way to "connect" WordPress content (for instance pages) with custom application/database developed by me.

My goal is to use WordPress as CMS (themes, content/articles management, gallery, authentication) and issue custom code on particular pages, for instance:

- on every access of some WordPress page query data from custom table created by me /not from std WordPress table/ like send request to controller, do some business logic and issue DB action, then return data
- write my own form on WordPress page, then send data to controller and perform DB actions

I came from Java and I have experience with MVC - thats why I mentioned controller and MVC "style".

What is common way to do that in WordPress? I am wondering where shall I "place/store" my custom Controllers and DAOs.

My idea is to write standalone MVC application and use REST API to exchange data between WordPress and my app. Im not sure whether "custom application" can be deployed somehow inside WordPress or need to stay as standalone application "next to" WordPress on server. Not sure if custom plugins may be utilized there. Or is there other way? If so, what are pros and cons of each?

Thanks!

Comment: WordPress does not have any frameworks for this kind of development. [`wpdb`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/) is available as a wrapper for the database, but apart from that you're on your own. To add code to WordPress, and to use WordPress' APIs, you will add your code to a plugin. The plugin development handbook is available here: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/